# sec:authentication is not working in Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a problem about showing not showing authenticated user full name.

I cannot see any values defined in `sec:authentication`.

Even through I defined sprng security and embedded it into my html code with supporting thymeleaf, the code didn't work.

How can I fix it?

Here is my CustomerUserDetails class

```
public class CustomerUserDetails implements UserDetails{

public String getFullName() {
        
        LOGGER.info("CustomerUserDetails | getFullName: " + customer.getFirstName() + " " + customer.getLastName());
        
        return customer.getFirstName() + " " + customer.getLastName();
    }


}
```

Here is the dependencies shown below.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my code shown below.

I only show this code shown below to show authenticated user full name

```
<a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/account_details}" ><b>[[${#request.userPrincipal.principal.fullName}]]</b></a>
```

Why doesn't sec:authentication work?

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show what didn't work?

Try something like:

```xml
<a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/account_details}"><b sec:authentication="name"/></a>
```

to verify that you have access to the
[Authentication](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/latest/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html)
instance.  Then try:

```xml
<a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/account_details}"><b sec:authentication="details"/></a>
```

and

```xml
<a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/account_details}"><b sec:authentication="details.fullName"/></a>
```

to verify your functionality.